# Set Content-Type with send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to send a file with a specific content type (`application/pkcs7-mime`) for Apple universal links.
I use the `send_file` function from rails, and add `:type` as a parameter,
but the type is always `text/plain`.

Here is my controller:

```
class AppleController < ApplicationController
  def download_app_site_association
    send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/apple-app-site-association", {:filename => "apple-app-site-association", :type => "application/pkcs7-mime" , :x_sendfile => true}
  end
end
```

I  also tried to add it like this:

```
send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/apple-app-site-association", :filename => "apple-app-site-association", :type => "application/pkcs7-mime" , :x_sendfile => true
```

and setting it manually like this:

```
response.headers["Content-type"] = "application/pkcs7-mime"
send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/apple-app-site-association", :filename => "apple-app-site-association", :x_sendfile => true
```

Can anyone explain me why this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem was that when i tried to get `mywebsite.com/apple-app-site-association`, the router was searching first for files in `#{Rails.root}/public/` and then searching for routes in `routes.rb`

As my file and my route had the same name, the `apple_controller` was never reached.

So I just changed the file name.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter you can set

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file

UPDATE: is the Mime type registered under config/initializers/mime_types.rb?

Comment: Yes there is, but as written in my question, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: No it is not registered, but i found the problem in my code and will post the answer. Thanks for help anyway